# How to abort model instance deletion from django model admin interface based on some condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to abort model deletion from django admin based on some condition.

I tried overriding `delete_queryset(self, request, queryset)` method.

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if not MyModel.objects.filter(is_active=True).exists():
            message = "Error message"
            raise ValidationError(message)
        super().delete_queryset(request, queryset)
```

This doesn't work since django does not handles exception at this stage.

Found this in Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_deleted_objects

But I am not sure how can I redirect from here to Django admin page where all model instances are listed and display the error message to user.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [**`.has_delete_permission(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission):

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # …
    
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if (my_condition):
            return False
        return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

Here `obj` is the object that will be removed. For example if you want to prevent removing an object with `is_active` is `True`, you can work with:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # …
    
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and obj.is_active:
            return False
        return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

Comment: My condition is based on the current instances in that Model. This solution will not help in that case. I have updated my question so that it is more clear.

Comment: @ShikharTyagi: well you can make a queryset in your `has_delete_permission`. I don't see what the problem is?

Comment: I am not sure how this will help, when admin selects multiple objects from admin panel and delete them together. In that case I would not want all objects selected should be deleted in that request, and show an error message on admin panel.